# Post class object with list in Shopware Customer Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, shopware

I want to post my data with list to shopware customer api. When I convert my class object in JSON, list is not included with all other data. But I am not getting how can I bind my list with all class object data and send to via api.
I want to send data like below example

```
{
    "email": "meier@mail.de",
    "firstname": "Max",
    "lastname": "Meier",
    "salutation": "mr",
    "billing": {
        "firstname": "Max",
        "lastname": "Meier",
        "salutation": "mr",
        "street": "Musterstrasse 55",
        "city": "Sch\\u00f6ppingen",
        "zipcode": "48624",
        "country": 2
    }
}
```

Here is my Class

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string email;
        public string salutation;
        public string title;
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public string street;
        public string city;
        public string zipcode;
        public int country;

        private List<Customer> billing;

        public Customer()
        {
        }

        public Customer(List<Customer> billing)
        {
            this.billing = billing;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
            List<Customer> billing = new List<Customer>();
                            billing.Add(new Customer()
                            {
                                firstname = "Hassas",
                                lastname = "sssss",
                                salutation = "mr",
                                street = "Haupt Str 11",
                                city = "abcddd",
                                zipcode = "4900",
                                country = 2
                            });
                            var shopCustomer = new Customer(billing);
                            shopCustomer.firstname = customers.FirstName;
                            shopCustomer.lastname = customers.LastName;
                            shopCustomer.email = customers.Email;
                            shopCustomer.salutation = "mr";

                            customershopwareApi.getCustomerRessource().add(shopCustomer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.email = "abc@gmail.com";
        customer.firstname = "abc";
        customer.lastname = "defg";
        customer.salutation = "mr";

        Billing billing = new Billing
        {
            firstname = "abc",
            lastname = "defgh",
            salutation = "mr",
            street = "Haupt str 11",
            city = "Hieer",
            zipCode = "4176",
            country = 2
        };
        customer.billing = billing;
        shopwareApi.getCustomerRessource().add(customer);
```